# Um Model pode utilizar um WebService para "regras de negócio"?

Tags: php, mvc

Ao usar alguns frameworks prontos (como Laravel e CodeIgniter), notei que os Models costumam ser estendidos de outras classes que geralmente conectam diretamente ao banco de dados, pelo que entendi isto não é obrigatório, pois o Model deve conter a *"logica do negócio"* ("regras de negócio") e não necessariamente conexões com bancos de dados.

Se o que entendi estiver correto, os frameworks fazem ao auto-conexão apenas para facilitar, assim quando usamos o Model as configurações do banco são carregadas automaticamente pelo framework no momento que o Model é "construído" conectando-se ao banco, ou seja é apenas para automatizar.

A minha duvida é a seguinte, eu posso utilizar um webservice *dentro* do Model, como sendo "equivalente" ao banco de dados?

Por exemplo (Note que este exemplo é completamente fictício):

```
class MyModel
{
    public function putItem($preco, $descricao)
    {
        $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'PUT /', array(
                                            'price' => $price,
                                            'description' => $descricao
                                        ));

        //Se o produto foi adicionado o HTTP status é 200 então putItem retorna TRUE
        return $response->status === 200;
    }

    public function deleteItem($id)
    {
        Rest('ws.example.com', 'DELETE /items/{id}', array(
                                            'id' => $id
                                        ));

        $response = json_decode($rest->getRespose());

        //Se o produto foi deletado o HTTP status é 200 então putItem retorna TRUE
        return $response->status === 200;
    }

    public function getItem($id)
    {
        $rest = Rest('ws.example.com', 'GET /items/{id}', array(
                                            'id' => $id
                                        ));

        $response = json_decode($rest->getRespose());
        if ($response->status === 200) {
            //Se o produto existe o HTTP status é 200 então retorna informações dele
            return $response->data;
        }

        //Se não retorna FALSE
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Ou devo fazer de outra maneira e qual seria está maneira?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso seria uma decisão de arquitetura muito arriscada.

Pense na seguinte situação. O seu model transita por todas as camadas de sua aplicação e logo você pode chamar esses métodos de web services em qualquer lugar. Isso é realmente o que você deseja? Fazer com que web services possam ser chamados de qualquer lugar? Imagine que seu objeto esteja na camada de DAO (Data Access Object), ou as vezes chamada de Repository. Você gostaria que web services fossem chamados alí?

Outra situação, imagine que você criar proxies de seus models para serem usados em aplicações clientes. Como eles são proxies, o que aconteceria caso esses métodos de web services sejam chamados?

Penso que seria mais interessante você delegar a chamada de web services em momentos e camadas específicas da sua aplicação. Sua arquitetura seria mais robusta dessa maneira.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, desculpe a demora a responder, está questão do MVC ainda é estranha para mim, sim entendi o motivo do "não usar" dentro do Model, se entendi corretamente o Model é para "representar o banco" na aplicação, então o uso do REST deveria ser dentro dos action diretamente, entendi certo? Por favor me corrija se eu estiver equivocado.